# Preview on Lion will open all images I opened last time, and need to close each window one by one?

Tags: macos, preview

Say if I clicked open 10 image files, and 2 PDF files, and quit Preview, then next time when I click on 1 image file or just start Preview, all those 12 other windows will open too...  I was playing a clicking game to close them one by one... is there a quick way to make Preview not do that or "Close All"?   (while keeping other apps to open the previous state).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [RestoreMeNot](http://restoremenot.info/) or [Tinker Tool](http://www.bresink.com/osx/TinkerTool.html) can be used to selectively control which apps restore their windows and should be able to do what you want.

Alternatively, using <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> in Preview (and most other apps) will close all currently open windows.

Comment: it does work... just wonder why OPT-CMD-w is not listed on the File menu

Comment: @動靜能量 It is, but its kind of hidden. You'll see it if you open the File menu and press the ⌥ key. The "Close Window" item changes to "Close All". This sort of thing is also the case for a lot of apps.

Comment: so the OPT key is a way to show more choices... the original list is shorten so that it is not exceedingly long... good to know, but sorry can't give you more up votes as i am limited to one vote

Comment: but the way I tried CTRL and CMD or Fn, and they don't do that... just the OPT key does

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to RestoreMeNot, you can run a command like this in Terminal:

```
defaults write com.apple.Preview NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool false
```

If others search for how to disable restoring state for all applications, enable this option:

[image]

I have disabled restoring state from System Preferences but enabled it just for Safari:

```
defaults write com.apple.Safari NSQuitAlwaysKeepsWindows -bool true
```